# RODBC "Communication link failure" error when reactively rerunning SQL queries in R shiny App

Tags: r, sql-server, shiny, rodbc, shiny-reactivity

I'm building a R shiny app that upon a button press runs 7 or so SQL queries to populate the dataframes behind m tables and graphs. The problem is sometimes when I start or refresh the data the queries don't return the data and I get a  "08S01 0 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Communication link failure" error.

I'm not entirely sure if this is a networking problem, the queries locking up the same table and failing or how the shiny app is set up.

Below is an example of how I'm structure the App and the database connection, something I'm almost certainly doing wrong as I'm mainly used markdown up until now.

```
library(RODBC)

connection <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(paste0("DRIVER={SQL Server};
                              server=",my_server,";
                              database=",my_db,";
                              uid=",my_username,";
                              pwd=",my_pwd)) 

ui <- dashboardPage(
...

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  full_table_query <- paste0("select distinct * from table")
full_table_query2 <- paste0("select distinct * from table2")  

values <- reactiveValues(full_table=NULL, full_table2=NULL)

values$full_table <- sqlQuery(connection, full_table_query)
values$full_table2 <- sqlQuery(connection, full_table_query2) 

observeEvent(input$refresh1, {

      values$full_table <- sqlQuery(connection, full_table_query)
      values$full_table2 <- sqlQuery(connection, full_table_query2)
}) 

output$full_table  <- DT::renderDataTable(values$full_table,
                                   filter = "top",
                                   options = list(scrollX = TRUE)
    )
...
```

A search online didn't throw up anything like this before but does anyone have any suggestions for why is going wrong?

Comment: "7 or so" connections isn't a high number since SQL Server itself is spec'd to handle over 32,000 concurrent connections. What is the network topology between the R Shiny app and the SQL Server? Does it need to traverse stateful firewalls, SSH tunnels, VPN tunnels, etc.? Is the SQL Server instance virtualized? e.g.: ESX/i guests have specific vNIC selection requirements that vary depending on the guest operating system, etc., and the wrong selection can lead to slow or intermittent connections.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning afraid I don't know that much about the network. The shiny app is running on my local machine and the SQL Server is running on a physical machine on a slightly different network through a VPN with a sql login. Never had problem running queries with SSMS for example.